# Retrieve sender public key from ethereum transactions

Tags: transactions, addresses, signature, public-key

I have tried using the eth_account library but it doesnt work on newer transactions (type 0x02 transactions). What is a method of retrieval that would work on those transactions?

```
from eth_account._utils.signing import extract_chain_id, to_standard_v, serializable_unsigned_transaction_from_dict 
from eth_account._utils.legacy_transactions import ALLOWED_TRANSACTION_KEYS

s = web3.eth.account._keys.Signature(vrs=(
    to_standard_v(extract_chain_id(tx.v)[1]),
    web3.toInt(tx.r),
    web3.toInt(tx.s)
))

tt = {k:tx[k] for k in ALLOWED_TRANSACTION_KEYS - {'chainId', 'data'}}
tt['data']=tx.input
tt['chainId']=extract_chain_id(tx.v)[0]

from eth_account._utils.legacy_transactions import serializable_unsigned_transaction_from_dict
ut = serializable_unsigned_transaction_from_dict(tt)

print('public key')
s.recover_public_key_from_msg_hash(ut.hash())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ethers.js Recover public key from contract deployment via v,r,s values](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78815/ethers-js-recover-public-key-from-contract-deployment-via-v-r-s-values)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this previously asked questions, you should find the answer there:

[ethers.js Recover public key from contract deployment via v,r,s values](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78815/ethers-js-recover-public-key-from-contract-deployment-via-v-r-s-values)

[How to recover sender's public key from a transaction json object with Ethers (Updated answers)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134110/how-to-recover-senders-public-key-from-a-transaction-json-object-with-ethers-u)

Comment: those solutions uses Js. Is there currently any method for python?

Comment: Yes sure, but with different library. This is for you: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/  

You can also check it out here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/python/